# Stored procedure that get array of Integers and 2 more ints , and inserts to another table?

Tags: arrays, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to write a stored procedure that gets an array of integers
and 2 more integers , and insert into a table all the values from the array 
with the 2 ints.

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.ContactsToInsert 
AS TABLE
(
  ContactId INT 
);


CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertMultipleContacts
  @ListOfContacts AS dbo.ContactsToInsert READONLY , 
  @MissionId INT ,
  @OwnerId INT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;  
  Insert into dbo.Missions
  values // insert here the contacts with the missionId and OwnerId


END
GO
```

How can I take all the integers from the array , with the two integers , and insert new records into `dbo.Missions` as the number of contacts in `@ListOfContacts` ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Does not understand your question properly, please write it properly
and try this

```
 Insert into dbo.Missions
 Select Row_Number() over (order by ContactId),ContactNo, @MissionId, @OwnerId
FROM @ListOfContacts
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
insert into dbo.Missions
select @MissionId, @OwnerId, ContactId from @ListOfContacts
```